# How to insert data to a database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net, sql-insert

I've just started to learn about databases and actually I've no idea why the code below doesn't work. I have searched a lot but I didn't realized what exactly is the happening.

I have a Windows Forms app and there are a `textbox` and a `button` in it. When I click on the button, the text inside the `textbox` should get inserted into the database, but nothing is actually happening.

I created the database with Visual Studio. I right-clicked on "Data connections" in Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2019 Community edition and then clicked on "Create New SQL Server Database".

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Initial Catalog = myTestDB; Integrated Security = True; Pooling = False")) 
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSER INTO [tesTable] VALUES (@fname, @lname)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", textBox2.Text);
}

MessageBox.Show("done!");
```

Comment: A command needs to be executed before anything happens database side. As a side note, you have used an INSERT command without naming the columns involved. This requires the database table to have exactly the same number of columns in the same exact order in which you add the parameters

Comment: I am suggesting to check the query  Sql Profiler after executing your query ,to know the exact query that is being implemented.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you haven't executed your command:

```
....
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", textBox2.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The fixed version of your `insert` statement should be something like this:

```
"INSERT INTO tesTable (fname,lname) VALUES (@fname,@lname)"
```

This also needs to be added, that specifying the type directly and use the `Value` property is more better than `AddWithValue`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
```

[Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: I did it but I'm getting this error after adding cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.'

Comment: Yes, two columns exactly.

Comment: @kiarashyoosefi What if you try this: `INSERT INTO tesTable (fname,lname) VALUES (@fname,@lname)` ? Just make sure the columns in sql are `fname` and `lname` exactly as well.

Comment: Notice the typo INSER INTO, missing the T...:-)

Comment: Also that _tesTable_ seems suspect. Probably the OP has a malfunctioning T key.

Comment: I changed insert statement to INSERT INTO testTable(firstName,lastName) VALUES (@fname,@lname) and also added cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
it solved

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnaddsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string connection1 = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=1234;database=library_system";
        con = new MySqlConnection(connection1);
        con.Open();
        string q = "Insert Into library_system.add_book(Book_No,Book_Name)values('"+tbbno.Text+"','" + tbbn.Text+ "')";
        cm1 = new MySqlCommand(q, con);
        cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //con.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("data saved", "information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        con.Close();
        // load();
        tbbno.Text = "";
        tbbn.Text = "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```